# MAMP: Instead of putting my files in the mamp folder, can I put it somewhere else and point to it?

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, port, mamp

Hi I am using MAMP not MAMP Pro and I am trying to put my production files in some other folders other than in the MAMP folder for easier organisation.

So what I have done,

**Host files**
To edit my system host file
1) In terminal, sudo nano /etc/hosts
2) Add 127.0.0.1       mysite.dev
3) control + o to save, control + x to exit

**In MAMP**
1) Edit httpd.conf to listen to 80 and uncomment #virtual hosts httpd-vhosts.conf
2) Edit httpd-vhosts.conf to include

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Users/eevenn.soh/Experiments/mysite"
ServerName mysite.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

**Chrome**
1) Now you will be able to navigate to mysite.dev in browser.

---

Not sure why it is not working for me?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have figured out. 
You will have to change some settings on your MAMP app.

Goto Preferences > Apache > Document Root

Change your Document Root to point to whatever directory you place your files.